# Should I use JMS for web logging?

Tags: jms

I am designing a web logging system. One of the requirement is to record the page request (multiple nodes) without significantly impacting web application performance. 
I have 2 implementations in mind:

1. insert data into remote database.
2. dispatch data as message via JMS. Let JMS handle retry attempts if the connection between the nodes and the web logger master system broken temporary.

Is the 2nd approach overkill?

Answer (score 1):

JMS should be a good approach for this.

You can achieve this with a simple log4j config.

http://www.slf4j.org/nlog4j/api/org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.html

Answer (score 1):

If remote logging is what you want, I think the second approach is the correct one.

Use Log4j JMSAppender to append messages to JMS Queue. Example of using JMS Appenders with ActiveMQ is at the following link,

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html

If you aren't using ActiveMQ just change InitialContextFactoryName and ProviderURL properties accordingly.